# Kotlin/Java nullability setting

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Given this Java interface in okhttp3.ws.WebSocketListener:

```
public interface WebSocketListener {
    (...)
    void onFailure(IOException e, Response response);
    (...)
}
```

Kotlin assumes a signature like this:

```
override fun onFailure(e: IOException, response: Response) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    (...)
}
```

If I now start my app in Airplane mode, it attempts to connect to the web socket. The web socket can't connect and returns a 'null' response to 'onFailure()' - which is correct at this point. But Kotlin checks that the response is null and crashes my app even before it can print the exception stack trace.

So: How do I force Kotlin to assume '@Nullable' for anything that is not annotated?

The setting should be project-wide, not system-wide.

Several searches on Google gave no usable results. So I wonder whether I am the first one to encounter this issue and whether Kotlin is ready for use already.

Do I really need to convert the class back to Java?

Comment: just mark the parameters as nullable

Comment: Some related [info](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-doesnt-kotlin-default-to-nullable-for-java-types/16753/2). You should be able to use `onFailure(e: IOException?, response: Response?)` in your interface to get the checks you need but I agree it's easy to miss...

Comment: Are you implementing your own `WebSocketListener` in kotlin? i.e. that second snippet is from a `class` und your control? Then you can just do: `response: Response?`. Please note that kotlin has no *project-wide* setting, you have to explicitly allow null using the `?` on a per-variable/-field basis.

Comment: I think this '?'-solution would work, so you all got an upvote. But I fear to implement further functions in Kotlin, since this way I can't make sure the Kotlin-stuff does everything right. I ported the class back and going to stick to Java for the time being. I just don't like surprises... The Kotlin-guys really should assume "?" for anything that comes from an interface/class that was written in Java.

Answer (score 4):

When dealing with a java type having no nullability information, you
can work with it as either a nullable or a nonnull type. meaning in your case you can simply change the type of `response` to `Response?`.

```
override fun onFailure(e: IOException, response: Response?) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    (...)
}
```

From [Kotlin in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action)

> sometimes Java
> code contains information about nullability,
> expressed using annotations. When this
> information is present in the code, Kotlin
> uses it. Thus `@Nullable String` in Java is
> seen as `String?` by Kotlin, and `@NotNull String` is just `String`. ***The interesting question is what happens when the annotations aren’t
> present. In that case, the Java type becomes a platform type in
> Kotlin.***

> **[PLATFORM TYPES](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types)**

> A platform type is essentially a type for which
> Kotlin doesn’t have nullability information; you can work with it as
> either a nullable or a nonnull type. This means, just
> as in Java, you have full responsibility for the operations you
> perform with that type.

Comment: Thank you. You got the upvote. As I want to implement my code without any warning (and without suppression annotations, if possible) I still wonder what places else I will encounter situations like this. I'd just be happier if I knew Kotlin had such a setting...